# Socket receiving no data. Why?

Tags: python, http, sockets

I was learning socket programming and tried to design a basic http client of mine. But somehow everything is going good but I am not receiving any data. Can you please tell me what am I missing?

**CODE**

```
import socket

def create_socket():
    return socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )

def remove_socket(sock):
    sock.close()
    del sock


sock = create_socket()
print "Connecting"
sock.connect( ('en.wikipedia.org', 80) )
print "Sending Request"
print sock.sendall  ('''GET /wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields HTTP/1.1
Host: en.wikipedia.org
Connection: close
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.37 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3
Referer: d_r_G_o_s
''')
print "Receving Reponse"
while True:
    content = sock.recv(1024)
    if content:
        print content
    else:
        break
print "Completed"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Connecting
Sending Request
298
Receving Reponse
Completed
```

While I was expecting it show me html content of homepage of wikipedia :'(

Also, it would be great if somebody can share some web resources / books where I can read in detail about python socket programming for HTTP Request Client

Thanks!

Comment: Are your newlines proper newlines (`'\r\n'`)? Also, after the headers you should have a single empty line, this tells the server that the headers are done.

Comment: No it wasnt.. I thought \n shall suffice but it doesnt.. I got it.. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a minimal HTTP client, you definitely shouldn't send `Accept-Encoding: gzip` -- the server will most likely reply with a gzipped response you won't be able to make much sense of by eye. :)

You aren't sending the final double `\r\n` (nor are you actually terminating your lines with `\r\n` as per the spec (unless you happen to develop on Windows with Windows line endings, but that's just luck and not programming per se).

Also, `del sock` there does not do what you think it does.

Anyway -- this works:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('en.wikipedia.org', 80))
for line in (
    "GET /wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: en.wikipedia.org",
    "Connection: close",
):
    sock.send(line + "\r\n")
sock.send("\r\n")

while True:
    content = sock.recv(1024)
    if content:
        print content
    else:
        break
```

EDIT: As for resources/books/reference -- for a reference HTTP client implementation, look at Python's very own `httplib.py`. :)

Comment: Most probably, the missing "\r\n" is the problem in the original code; the Wikipedia webserver closes the connection as soon as it sees invalid/broken HTTP headers.

Comment: @AKX: thank you.. . I was using only \n. And httplib.py as a reference sounds great!! :)

Comment: @AKX: What does del sock do what I think it doesnt? :p

Comment: @dragosrsupercool: it deletes the name from the scope it is in, namely the `remove_socket` function -- doing it there, just before the function is exited, does nothing worthwhile. (You very rarely actually need `del` in Python code anyway.)